# ctrl+D not working in mail

Tags: ubuntu, putty

I am trying to test the mail capabilities of my server. I simply do this `mail -s "This is a test" myemail@domain.com`, then it prompts me for `Cc:` then the body. After typing I am hitting Control + D, however it seems that it is not exiting in the body. What am I missing here?

Comment: it takes "." as end statement are you providing it ?

Comment: Depending on the `mail` version IIRC you need to end the message with a new line containing a single `.` dot when you run mail interactively.

Comment: Tried adding `.` in it still I got no response even if I keep on pressing the Control + D. Seems that Putty is not sending the keyboard press the right way.

Comment: You can check if it is a Putty problem by simply logging in to virtually anything (bash, zsh, mysql, whatever) and pressing Ctrl+D. This is equivalent to typing `exit` so it should log you out. If you don't get logged out, it might be a Putty issue. However, if your `mail` program doesn't send e-mail after feeding the body through a pipe, then it's more probably a `mail` issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a mail with a single line

`echo "This is the mail body" | mail -s "This is the subject" myemail@domain.com`

without the need of any further typing.

Comment: Tried this and it seems that it doesn't proceed. It seems like I need to type a body message.

Answer (score 3):

This may happen because of misconfiguration of `mail`.

To understand the problem, turn on the debug regime, e.g.:

```
$mail -s "test" me@example.com --debug-level=3
Cc: 
Hello. This is a test.
.
.(doesn't work until Ctrl+D, I'm using mailutils package)
.
sendmail (/usr/sbin/sendmailn
source=system, name=user, passwd=x, uid=1000, gid=1000, gecos=,,,, dir=/home/user, shell=/bin/bash, mailbox=/var/mail/user, quota=0, change_uid=1
source=system, name=user, passwd=x, uid=1000, gid=1000, gecos=,,,, dir=/home/user, shell=/bin/bash, mailbox=/var/mail/user, quota=0, change_uid=1
mu_mailer_send_message(): using From: user@example
Sending headers...
Sending body...
^C
```

(note the misconfigured user@example)

So the process stops sending body. You can also examine `/var/log/mail.{err,log}`. To configure smtp properly, see e.g. [this](http://rianjs.net/2013/08/send-email-from-linux-server-using-gmail-and-ubuntu-two-factor-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Yaroslav's excellent answer from 2016, a common misconfiguration is that the hostname is not configured correctly. Sendmail requires a fully qualified domain name to send mails, but is easily tricked into believing that the hostname `myhostname` is such by adding that name to the first line in `/etc/hosts`, as described here: https://linuxconfig.org/sendmail-unqualified-hostname-unknown-sleeping-for-retry-unqualified-hostname